# Horror/thriller about a house which consists of rooms from other flats/houses in each of which happened deaths

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I'm looking for a horror/thriller about a house which consists of rooms from other flats/houses and in each of them happened deaths.

I saw only the trailer about this house. The whole trailer was very dark. There was a narrator who was an old respectable man in a black suit and with a walking-stick. The narrator says that he bought the ground and rooms from all over the world in which happened strange deaths. And he brought all these rooms together and connected them in one house.

As I remember it had 2-3 floors with an attic and was a very dark house. The house is situated in town, rounded by other houses. Only sky is full of white clouds.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). Can you maybe add some other details you remember? Maybe also some external information, like when you wtached the trailer approximately, from when the movie was approximately, or from which country.

Comment: I saw it in russia, but movie isn't russian 100%. Trailer was with russian audio-track. I saw trailer approximately year ago or less. And movie must be released 2016 or 2017 but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think it's Silent Hill.
It could be "The Shining" or oddly may be "The cabin in the woods" as the movie portrays many floors and elements suggested in the question.

Comment: No, I saw "Silent Hill", "The Shining" and "The cabin in the woods" - they have another plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Abattoir](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1480285/combined) (2015), found it by myself.

> An investigative reporter works to solve the mystery of a haunted house constructed from rooms of the deceased.

The trailer is available in [this Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNArt3I1_us#t=33m38s).